# Ajax is not getting results

Tags: ajax

I just got into ajax and I cannot understand what is wrong about the code?

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ajax call</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<head>
<body>
    <script>
        var UserID = 'myname';
        var EmailAddress = 'myname@mail.com';

        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            type: "get",        //send it through get method
            data: 
                { 
                    ajaxid: 4, 
                    UserID: UserID, 
                    EmailAddress: EmailAddress
                },
            success: function(response) 
                {
                //Do Something
                Alert("Sucess");
                },
            error: function(xhr) 
                {
                //Do Something to handle error
                Alert("Failure");
                }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . ' => ' . $value . '<br />';
    }   
?>
```

After resolving this issue, my main goal is to replace the code in the php file with a function that connects to a SQL Server and retrieve some data using the data sent by the ajax call. **I will try this later**.

Regards, 
Elio Fernandes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Alert("smth")` to `alert("smth")`
Then in `success` function you need to "send" server response to html

```
success:function(response){
    alert('success')
    $('body').append(response)
}
```

Comment: Bart, the success message is showing now. Why the there is no echo of the GET global arry in the php file?